# Changing LinearLayout Height from top (default from bottom) in Android programmatically (Java)

Tags: java, android

I want to change the height of a LinearLayout and works everything OK, but I want height decreasing and increasing from the top (the defaults starts decreasing and increasing from the bottom).

Here is an example:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findById(R.id.layout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParameters layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParameters) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = linearLayout.getHeight() - 1;
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This works OK. The only thing I wanna change is the direction of height change. 
Thanks for the replay.

Comment: you can try setting margin Layout params with margin-top equal to height elapsed, it will push the view giving the illusion what you are trying.

Comment: @mudit_sen that might be in hand in versions prior jelly bean. thank you for contributing to the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by binding(the bottom) of your linear layout inside a constraint layout,
Also is there a parent to your linear layout?, if so then it being unbound might be the reason

Comment: The LinearLayout is inside another LinearLayout that is inside a RelativeLayout (root)

Comment: can you provide the complete code for the layout a screenshot of the app would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I achieved changing the direction with the setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE) from teh ViewGroup class. Also had to change layout's gravity to bottom in the xml.
Thanks for contribute to my answer.